# How can i create a Console Window for a nogui process started in java?

Tags: java, console, window, cmd, processbuilder

When I start a process without a GUI in Java, no console (`cmd.exe`) window is opened.

Example:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("process", nogui);
Process process = builder.start();
```

How can I see the console window?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java

Comment: thx :) this is perfectly what i searched.

Comment: Can't quite parse that.  Did what that question recommended work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c process nogui");
```

For Other OS; Similar :)

Comment: thx for the answer :) , but it doesnt work :(, the process is in the list in the taskmgr (its java.exe), but the window isnt visible...