# Is there any way to create ARP cache entries programatically in windows using java?

Tags: mapping, arp

I want to add arp ip to mac mapping to arp cache using programming languages preferably java.

Comment: Actually i didnt found any way rather just a trick that we can write strings to command promt using java so we can write arp -s                                                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java                                                                   http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-execute-command-prompt-command-view-output-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run the command ARP -s inet_addr eth_adr where inet_addr is the IP address and eth_adr is the hardware address.
In Java:

```
 Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -s 220.0.0.161 00-50-04-62-F7-23");
```

In c#:

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "arp -s 220.0.0.161 00-50-04-62-F7-23";
 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //Don't show window
 process.Start();
```