# how can cmd.exe be launched from java?

Tags: java, process, cmd

in .net if I wanted to open a new command line window, I could just write.

```
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe");
```

in java, however, the following code does nothing:

```
    new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").start();
    java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
```

No new window is created and no Process appears in Task Manager.

Now if the application I was trying to open was "notepad.exe", then java would open it just fine.

What does this mean?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java) (read: probably not dupe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start"});
```

To [learn more on start](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm), type `help start` at command prompt.