# call another class from java program

Tags: java, class, call

I have 2 classes one is a simple one

Sample.java

```
public class Sample {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Hello World!!!!!");
  }
}
```

Other one is something like this

Main.java

```
public class Main
{  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Sample");
  }
}
```

I am basically trying to run the Main.java program to call Sample.java in a new command prompt...that is a new cmd that should open and print the output of Sample.java...how should I do this...???

Comment: And what is the outcome if you execute `Main`?

Comment: what you got in your result?

Comment: I think it is laready answered, you can check this - [How to open the command prompt and insert commands using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java)

Comment: nothing it just shows blank....

Comment: Are you asking this because you want to learn about `exec` ? Or do you just dont know how to invoke methods in another class?

Comment: I know how to invoke methods from other class...the main problem is to execute the command in another cmd and then show the output there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd <where_the_Sample_is> && javac Sample.java && java Sample\"");
```

or if the class is already compiled:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd <where_the_Sample_is> && java Sample\"");
```

Comment: this work but the problem here is that it shows the ouput for fraction of a second and then closes..any idea as to how retain the new commandpromt..??

Comment: try adding " && pause" at the end of the command, for example:
"cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd <where_the_Sample_is> && java Sample && pause\"

Comment: doesnt work...it still exists

Comment: okay I was able to make it halt by using getInt();

Answer (score 4):

Compile the two together, and then from Sample,

```
Main.main(args);
```

will do the trick. You don't need to import since you're in the same package. 
Note the linked tutorial.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Comment: @RahulMehrotra Can you accept this answer if it works for you?

Comment: bro ..this is not what I am exactly looking for but heads up for the help....

Answer (score 2):

I am using eclipse. The class files are placed in the bin directory located under the projects directory. The below code starts command prompt, changes directory to bin and issues java Sample command. You can edit it up to your requirement.

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cd \"bin\" & start cmd.exe /k \"java Sample\"");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<Sample> clazz = Sample.class;
        Method mainMethod = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        String[] params = null;
        mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) params);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually need to start a new cmd prompt and show the output there...thanks a lot for your help...:)

Comment: Go to the directory where is Main.class is put and use java command: java Main

Comment: Make sure that Main.class and Sample.class are in the same directory, otherwise you must use -classpath option of the "java" command line

Comment: it is showing an error as cannot find the class Method

Comment: Can you copy and past here the error ?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
        Method mainMethod = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        ^
  symbol:   class Method
  location: class Main1
1 error

Comment: are you imported Method class ? "import java.lang.reflect.Method;"