# With Java, run multiple commands in the same cmd.exe window

Tags: java, windows, cmd, runtime

I'm developing a Java application that will be run on a Windows computer occasionally.
At some point I need to run a Cygwin prompt and performs some commands in it.

I've found a topic where the Runtime class is used:
http://www.javaquery.com/2011/03/how-to-execute-multiple-command-in.html

However it doesn't launch a real **cmd.exe** window, it's only run in background and the output is just printed on the Eclipse console.

I'm looking for a solution to run a real **cmd.exe** window and I need to pass as many commands as I want to that windows shell.
Is this possible?

Comment: this might help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java

Comment: So you need a command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute cmd commands via Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java)

Comment: yes duplicate question, but the solution given in that topic wasn't working for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one works... using && operator you can add one or commands to be executed in same command prompt

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime
                    .getRuntime()
                    .exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"dir && ping localhost && echo end\"");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Consider the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157303/how-to-execute-cmd-commands-via-java) also

**Update from the questioner: Solution to execute commands in cygwin**

```
getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe --login -c \"ls ; whoami ; exec bash\"");
```

Comment: Your solution works great for Windows command indeed thanks ! However when I run this : 
    .exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe && ls\"");
It does executes the cygwin terminal inside cmd.exe but it doens't execute the ls command inside cygwin terminal ? Why is that ?

Comment: it opens a cmd.exe windows, then displays "/usr/bin/bash: /K No such file or directory" and closes it immediatly after

Comment: I found the solution thanks to part of your code and the bash manual : 
.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe --login -c \"ls ; whoami ; exec bash\"");   
Thanks ! Can you edit your post with that line of code please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to show a console on the screen, that is easy. You have some simple steps to follow :

- start a `Process` via `Process cmd = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").start();
- send your commands to `cmd.getOutputStream()`
- read the result of the commands from `cmd.getInputStream()` and/or `cmd.getErrorStream()`
- when finished with it close `cmd.getOutputStream()`, and if necessary kill the process by `cmd.destroy()`

Optionnaly, you can have output and error stream to be merged :

```
Process cmd = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
```

then you simply ignore `cmd.getErrorStream()` and only read from `cmd.getInputStream()`

Comment: Actually, as mentionned I need to show the console, but thanks it can be useful in the future

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure , but if i properly understand your problem , try : for windows at java conifguration panel, there should be un-ticked the show console button.

Comment: This can be a comment

Comment: I didn't found the checkbox you're refering to, but I think it's not relevant to my issue because I don't want to see an Eclipse console but the actual Windows cmd prompt

Comment: not at eclipse configurations. type at your windows search java config