# Execute commands in cmd using Java

Tags: java

I am using the following code to run the cmd.exe and the cmd window appears which is fine.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process p = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0l0c.png)

**My question is that how can I run the following command on the cmd before it appears using java**

```
ghci test.hs
```

my target is to make the command line looks like the following image once it appears

[imag2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LudIu.png)

Comment: Do you need the cmd for path or something? You could call the ghci.exe or ghci.com directly with params I guess?

Comment: @DanielPersson I tried to call ghci earlier it works, however the cmd window does not appear.

Comment: so you want to run cmd /c ghci.exe test.ha?

Comment: /c stands for command.

Comment: @DanielPersson yes exactly and appear the command line window image number 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();      
try { 
    Process p = runtime.exec("start cmd.exe /k \"ghci.exe test.hs\""); 

} catch (IOException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
}
```

referens 
http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

more info at [How to open the command prompt and insert commands using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java)

Comment: try adding start before cmd

Comment: adding start caused this error :    Dec 12, 2015 3:16:20 PM ui.Main Programmar1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: @haskell00 try adding start before

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave me a clue to my problem. I solved the problem using this command     Process p = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c cd \""+ "C:\\Users\\WIN8\\Desktop\\test" +"\" & start cmd.exe /k \"ghci test.hs\"");