# Opening cmd and waiting user input in cmd and exec commands from java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

My problem is, after opening cmd from java code, i want user to be able to input like in c++ ms dos applications. When user writes sth such as "dir" or "cd..", i want to execute these codes by java.
The problem is for every command java re-opens cmd again. Also i cannot execute commands. My cmd start code is below ;

```
final ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();                

    commands.add("cmd.exe");
    commands.add("/C");
    commands.add("start");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    Process process = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some cleaned up code from [How to open the command prompt and insert commands using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String ss = null;
        Runtime obj = null;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");


        //write a command to the output stream
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write("dir");
        writer.flush();

        //Get the input and stderror
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));


        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((ss = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ss);
        }

        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((ss = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ss);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("FROM CATCH" + e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Though it does not open cmd window from netbeans. Probably when i export the project as jar, maybe it will open cmd?

Comment: Also it does not write outputs to netbeans log window for example when i try dir etc

Comment: Does it succeed on the call for cmd.exe?