# how to prompt "open file window" from command prompt in java?

Tags: java, file, command-prompt, openfiledialog

I am trying to prompt "open file window" from command prompt in java and planning to take that selected file as input file instead of

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(args[0]);
```

but not succeeded yet, please some tell me how to do it in command prompt in java.

Comment: Maybe it's solution you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688123/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-and-insert-commands-using-java

Comment: You're looking for the JFileChooser class. FileInputStream is an inputstream, not a popup window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to be able to select a file from a dialog box.

Assuming you want to launch it outside a Java Swing application, you could proceed as next:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
// Open the dialog using null as parent component if you are outside a
// Java Swing application otherwise provide the parent component instead
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // Retrieve the selected file
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

More details about [**How to Use File Choosers**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)